# Render a WordPress post outside of wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress, rendering, external

I am trying to show wordpress posts outside of the wordpress framework. I have access to the wordpress database and am able to retrieve posts from the `wp_post` table, but the HTML in the `post_content` column isn't the same as in the actual blog. For example, if I have an image caption, it shows up in the `post_content` column as

```
[caption id="attachment_23" align="aligncenter" width="218"]Caption test[/caption]
```

Is there any way that I can render the database HTML so that it shows up the same as on the actual blog. I am not worried about styling and would actually prefer it if the HTML isn't styled at all.

Please help as much as you can.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the XML-RPC API: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support instead of accessing directly the database.

It will be easier to render the posts.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ugly solution, but if you have WordPress installed but don't want to use in the traditional way, for whatever reason, you can use `wp_load.php`. Just do `require_once(PATH_TO_WORDPRESS/wp_load.php)`, then you'll have access to all the WordPress features, including The Loop.